# Is it possible to invert a splat in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, operators, inverse, splat

Ruby's splat operator `*` may be used to coalesce

```
def one_argument(*a)
  ...
end

one_argument(1, 2, 3)
```

or split

```
def multiple_arguments(a, b, c)
  ...
end

multiple_arguments(*[1, 2, 3])
```

multiple values, depending on the context.

Is it possible to create a method that acts as an "inverse splat" operator? To act as an inverse, the operator must satisfy:

```
inverse_splat(*(foo)) == foo
```

and

```
*(inverse_splat(foo)) == foo
```

Comment: Your question is confusing. What would be the result of `inverse_splat(*(foo bar))` or `*(inverse_splat(foo, bar))`?

Comment: What is `foo`?  Will be nice if you can share something more easier to understand example cases for reverse splat - just like the ones you shared for splat

Comment: @WandMaker Probably an arbitrary object.

Comment: @SimoneCarletti @WandMaker @sawa I'm sorry the question was confusing. I've edited it to emphasize the 'is it possible?' over the 'how would you do it?'. I didn't mean to assume in the question that `inverse_splat` was well-defined or possible. Let me know if it's still unclear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Regarding `*(inverse_splat(foo))`, it does not make sense. The result of splatting is in general a sequence of objects, which is not an object. Such thing cannot exist in Ruby.

  And at this point, the assumption you seem to making, i.e., that the order of `inverse_splat` and `*` are interchangable, turns out to be false.
- Regarding `inverse_splat(*(foo))`

  There cannot be such inverse. That is because the splat `*` internally calls `to_a`, which is not a one-to-one mapping.

  ```
  [[:a, 1], [:b, 2]].to_a
  # => [[:a, 1], [:b, 2]]
  {a: 1, b: 2}.to_a
  # => [[:a, 1], [:b, 2]]
  ```

  An inverse can only be defined on a one-to-one map.

  If you disregard such cases and want to still explore if there is something close to it, then a close thing is the `[`...`]` literal.

Answer (score 4):

A simple example in addition to [sawa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34638263/477037):

```
def inverse_splat(*args)
  args
end

inverse_splat(*nil) #=> []
inverse_splat(*[])  #=> []
inverse_splat(*{})  #=> []
inverse_splat()     #=> []
```

All of the above invoke the method in the same way. There's no way to distinguish the invocations from within the method and therefore, you can't reconstruct the original object.